# Check my solution for How to find nth element from the end of a singly linked list

Tags: java

This question is already solved but I solved this question in another way. I just wanted to know whether I am correct or not.

My code is:

```
public static Object nthToLast(int n, LinkedList list)
{
    int len = list.size();
    if(n<0 || len<n)
        return null;
    return list.get(len-n);
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: This question belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks. I will post it over there too.

Comment: What is the point of doing `list.get(len-n);` without assigning it to anything, and then printing it out?

Comment: You should move this question, which also means you should remove it from here as it is not really a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static Object nthToLast(int n, LinkedList list)
{
    int len = list.size();
    if(n<0 || len < n){
      return null;
    }
    return list.get(len-n);
}
```

Comment: So this solution will also work for this question and my approach is correct right?

Answer (score 0):

why did you put

```
list.get(len-n);
System.out.println(list.get(len-n));
```

separately?

```
 System.out.println(list.get(len-n));
```

will work fine.

Also, since you haven't really clarified the way you're counting, you'll probably want to use `len = list.size()-1;` That way, it's the same convention as starting from the front, where the last element is at n = 0, the second to last is at n = 1, etc.

And as rahulroc did, make sure you check to see if the value you're checking is within the list, otherwise it will give an error.

Comment: That was a mistake using the same thing 2 times. I am not subtracting the value because then that will give a wrong answer or I will have to add 1 later in the code.